# Get real fee per transaction

Tags: bitcoind, bitcoin-cli, fee-estimation

I am trying to get real fee per trasnaction.

So I have an account whit balance `0.06940000` and have a second account with balance `0.00000000`.

To get current fee I have run the command

```
bitcoin-cli getmempoolinfo
```

and got the `mempoolminfee = 0.00001000`.
I thought that when I send the `0.06939000` in my account rest balance will `0.00000000`. but I got `0.00004860`. Actually the fee was  `0.0000514`.

general question is WhY ?

Please tell me to understand how is fees working!

Answer (score 1):

What `getmempoolinfo` is returning is not the minimum fee to send a transaction, but the minimum **rate per kilobyte** to send a transaction. Your bitcoin client will take the configured fee and multiply it by the size of the transaction in kilobytes to calculate the actual transaction fee.

The size of a transaction is somewhat difficult to compute (for a person) because it requires understanding the number of inputs that are required to fulfil the transaction, the number of outputs (primary recipients + change address), and the targeted transaction fee (since appropriate fees could eliminate the need for a change address).

There are online fee calculators out there you can use to estimate these, but it is still difficult to completely empty a wallet with a known fee using the straight bitcoin client.

Comment: Is there a way to get fee before sending transaction ?

Comment: No, but if all you are looking to do is empty a wallet, you can pass an argument to `sendtoaddress` which will take the fee out of the sent amount rather than the wallet you're sending from--you will receive less bitcoin than you "sent", but you will be able to empty the wallet.

See argument #5 for `sendtoaddress`: https://bitcoin.org/en/developer-reference#sendtoaddress

Comment: thanks! but what when i want to send bitcoins from specific account to address?

Comment: Again, if you want to remove a specific amount from the sending address, you set that 5th argument to true. If you want a specific amount to be received by the recipient address, you leave it set to false.